# How to replicate bash's escaping on commands passed as arguments to other commands

Tags: python, bash, pycharm, escaping

Edit 2: Bit of a late edit to summarise the comments on this question. I misunderstood how bash works, and confused it with how python works. I presumed Bash escaped the output of the `kubectl` command, so it wouldn't be broken up into multiple arguments when passed to the python command. (i.e. how you would escape quotes in python strings to stop the string being broken up.)

Actually, when surrounding the output of a command in quotes, Bash is able to pass the output of the execution of a command, as a single argument. It does not escape anything, it simply doesn't try and interpret it all either. The issue I was having is actually PyCharm's lack of functionality to pass complex strings as a single argument, and it is PyCharm that parses strings with spaces as multiple arguments.

---

I'm passing the result of the execution of a command to python as input, like so:

```bash
$ python parse_ips.py "$(kubectl get configmap ...)"
```

This works fine when executing from the command line, however I'm now trying to edit the file using PyCharm. Therefore I need the escaped version of the result of this command which I can paste into PyCharm's debug configuration, as I can't execute the command in real-time like I can do on the command line.

However, I am struggling to find a way to replicate the escaping bash does behind the scenes, so I can use the result as an argument within the PyCharm configuration. Running the above `kubectl` command results in a multi-line string which includes spaces and quotes. When I paste this into PyCharm it just interprets it as multiple arguments. I'm looking for the escaped result, which I could paste directly into the command line, or into PyCharm's debug configuration, to achieve the same result with a fixed parameter for testing.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Edit: To clarify, I mean on the command line the result of the `$(kubectl ...)` command is passed into the python program as a single command line argument when it is surrounded by quotes (`"$(kubectl ...)"`). So in the python program, you can access `sys.argv[1]` and it will contain the entire execution output of `$(kubectl get configmap ...)`. However, if I execute that command myself on the command line, the result is a multi-line string.

If I then copy the result of that into PyCharm (or even on the command line again), it is interpreted as many command line arguments. E.g. it would look something like this:

```bash
$ python parse_ips.py apiVersion: v1
data:
  item1: ifconfig-push 127.0.0.0 255.255.0.0
  item2: ifconfig-push 127.0.0.1 255.255.0.0
  item3: ifconfig-push 127.0.0.2 255.255.0.0
  ...
```

And so on. This obviously doesn't work in the same way as it did before. So I am unable to test my program without making the `kubectl` call from the command line each time. I was looking to replicate what `"$(kubectl ...)"` gets converted into so it is able to pass the entire output as a single command line entry.

Comment: Can you clarify what escaping you mean? There is no escaping in the code shown, and Python generally needs less escaping than bash.

Comment: I guess you're looking for `PYCHARM_ARGS="\"$(kubectl get configmap ...)\""` ?

Comment: Hey there guys, sorry for the confusion! I updated the question with an edit, does that clarify?

Comment: You should be able to just ``'`` quote the entire input.

Comment: Further down the result of the command execution also contains `'` and `"` characters, so I would have to manually escape all of these.

Comment: `o achieve the same result with a fixed parameter for testing.` I do not understand. You can safely do `"blabla <newline> bnlabla"` in command line with a "fixed" parameter. You can use `printf "%q"` to do quoting, like `"$(printf "%q  "$(kubectl get configmap ....)")"`, but I do not understand how that would help.

Comment: " I would have to manually escape all of these." Well, erm... yes? Sorry, it's not clear what you are looking for. Are you searching some code/utility/helper that *automatically* converts the "literal" input (for bash? for Python?) to the appropriately escaped bash command line argument?

Comment: Then do `a=$(kubectl get configmap ...); something something "$a"`? No, bash does not "perform escaping", what escaping does is disabling word splitting.

Comment: Let me try my best to explain more clearly. So the main aim is I don't want to make the `kubectl` call every time. Let's stick with the command line example. I presume behind the scenes somewhere, bash takes the output of `$(kubectl get configmap ...)` and performs the necessary escaping so it can be passed as a single argument to the next process. So that regardless of new-line characters/ quotes/ etc in the output, it still gets passed as one argument. I was wondering if there was a way to replicate this behaviour and get the 'escaped' version of the output of the command.

Comment: `scenes somewhere, bash takes the output of $(kubectl get configmap ...) and performs the necessary escaping` No. There is no "escaping". Bash passes the output of a command _verbatim_ as it is without any modifications (ok, except, `$(..)` removes trailing empty lines). What do you want to do? You want to copy the output of a command with your mouse and paste it in another terminal as one argument? Why not use a file for example?

Comment: Bash does not "prevent", _it is bash_ that splits the result of expansions to multiple arguments __if__ the expansion is not inside double-quotes. It's bash that does the splitting. If the argument is inside double quotes, then word splitting (and filename expansion) are not performed.

Comment: Ahhh, okay, I misinterpreted then. Yeah so the main desire was to copy this "escaped" version I thought existed and copy it into the PyCharm debug configuration, so I could replicate the behaviour of calling `python parse_ips.py "$(kubectl get configmap ...)"` in PyCharm and use it's tooling capabilities. A file is a potential option and I might go down that route, thanks for the suggestion. I was just looking for something where I wouldn't have to change the python code as the end use of this python program will be from the command line.

Comment: `I wouldn't have to change the python code` Why would you change it?

Comment: Ahh I see, so actually wrapping it in quotes disables bash's interpretation of quotes and spaces, so I guess I would have to dig into PyCharm and replicate the behaviour there. As a follow up, how does the output of the command contain quotes (`"`)? I would have thought this would clash with the quotes surrounding the command?

Comment: I would have to change the python code to read the command output from a file when editing the python code from PyCharm, no?

Comment: Why not `command "$(cat file)"`?

Comment: Ahh I've just seen your answer, looks very useful, let me try it out, thanks!

Comment: As far as I'm aware PyCharm debug configurations don't support executing bash commands as part of supplying paramters to the program. So I need the output of the command, in plain-text, as a single argument somehow. Or a workaround!

Comment: Hey @KamilCuk, just moved house and finally found some time to come back to this question and update it with your findings, thanks again for that :) as a follow up, you say that bash passes the output verbatim to the next command, but I was wondering how it deals with quotation marks? Say if the `kubectl` command resulted in `data: "some value"`. Then `python parse_ips.py "$(kubectl ...)"` would get passed as `python parse_ips.py "data: "some value""`, but then the quotations would contradict each other, so does bash escape these quotations or..?

Comment: Add `set -x` and see the output. `set -x ; python parse_ips.py "$(kubectl ...)"`. Bash has the power here and bash interprets all the strings. There is no need for bash to add quotation to later remove them. It's bash that manages that. What would be the point - get the output of `kubectl ...`, quote it, then unquote it, then pass to `python`. Bash just passes the actual result.

Comment: Ahh thanks for the idea of adding `set -x`! Interesting however, bash does appear to escape single quotes. I used your idea of reading from a text file and added the line `name: 'openvpn'`, with `set -x` it appears bash translates it to `name: '\''openvpn'\'''`. However `printf "%q" "$(cat file.txt)"` outputs `name: \'openvpn\'`. Do you have idea why these are different?

Comment: @dylanmorroll In case you are not aware: What you type into bash's REPL is *not* the verbatim information. When you type something like ``cat "foo bar"`` into bash, then bash *parses* this to the separate ``cat`` and ``foo bar``. The ``"`` and escapes and all that are so that *you* can type things into the REPL, which inherently is restricted to a single character stream. Internally, bash has no problem working with the verbatim information directly; it doesn't need to escape anything that it already has.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I am struggling to find a way to replicate the escaping bash does behind the scenes

Typically use `printf "%q"` to escape stuff.

```
printf "%q" "$(kubectl get configmap ....)"
```

This is `printf` as the bash builtin command. It differs from coreutils `printf`, and newest ones also support `%q` with different quoting style:

```
/usr/bin/printf "%q" "$(kubectl get configmap ....)"
```

Modern bash also has quoting expansion:

```
var="$(kubectl get configmap ....)"
echo "${var@Q}"
```

And there is also the quoting style outputted by `set -x`.

---

I would suggest to use a file:

```
kubectl get configmap ... > /tmp/tempfile
python parse_ips.py "$(cat /tmp/tempfile)"
```

With `xclip` you can copy command output straight to the X server clipboard, which is handy:

```
printf "%q" "$(kubectl get configmap ...)" | xclip -selection clipboard

# then in another window:
python parse_ips.py <right mouse click><select paste>
```

Comment: Hey there, thanks for this, this is great! Didn't know about `printf` and `xclip` is also very useful. This works great on the command line and as intended! Unfortunately it doesn't work pasting it into the PyCharm debug configuration as a parameter, it goes and splits up the result on spaces, but from your explanation earlier that might be a PyCharm thing rather than a bash thing. Thanks for all the help! I'll get round to updating my question with all your helpful information when I find some more time :)

Comment: As in something PyCharm does, rather than something bash prevents.